# How to simulate command line or terminal in iOS?

Tags: ios, command-line

How can I make an app that simulates a command line or terminal?  Can I use built-in controls or do I have to make something custom?  Can someone point me to some sample code?  All searches I conduct result in Cisco-related iOS stuff and not Apple-related results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to do the same thing. I found this project:

http://code.google.com/p/mobileterminal/

may be this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I will check this out.  It may be more than what I actually want as I just want to have UI that emulates a command-line so I can have my program behave like a console app.  I don't need actual shell functionality.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're asking, but you can call system(); to call bash scripts(command line stuff). There is no pre-built terminal shell view in Apple's iOS SDK. You have to have a few popen commands called. You also need to learn how to thread or some of your processes will be interrupted.

I've also heard that sometimes system() may not be the best way to call bash scripts for performance, security reasons etc.

Try to look at the NSTask class if you're planning to submit to App Store. This class keeps the scripts within controlled code, but it doesn't come with elevated priviledges.

Comment: I dont want to access the system's command line.  I just want to make a user interface that mimics one for my own use, i.e., to make a telnet program, ZORK game, or something similar.  I was hoping for something other than a big text box and a separate input field.